# Django Deploy to cPanel: Passengerfile.json' for reading: Permission denied (errno=13)

Tags: python, django, server, shared-hosting

I am trying to deploy my first Django application via my GoDaddy cPanel. I created my application in a virtual environment, but I'm stuck. I installed django then create wsgi file also. but now when I run the site it shows me this:

```
Passenger error #2
An error occurred while trying to access '/home/u4sgzlaz0pwz/repositories/rentaltake/Passengerfile.json': Error opening '/home/u4sgzlaz0pwz/repositories/rentaltake/Passengerfile.json' for reading: Permission denied (errno=13)

Apache doesn't have read permissions to that file. Please fix the relevant file permissions.
```

Comment: Is that file in the same directory as your application?  Do you know what the permissions are?

Comment: yes pessangers file is also in the same directory as manage.py(application root folder)...I don't have any idea about these permissions here. just want to run a django app online. what am I doing wrong?..thank you

Comment: You have to know the permissions.  The file needs to be created with 644 permissions to allow Apache to read your files.

Answer (score 5):

I was running into this same issue, I found the answer to my problem  [here](https://parmarnaitik0909.medium.com/deploying-hosting-a-django-website-on-cpanel-with-git-version-control-6e8dce70a316). If you are deploying the app in a sub directory (in my case repositories) then you need to adjust the permissions on that directory to 755. Look at the upstream directory permissions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30559333)

Comment: Is that not what I did in the following sentence: If the app is being deployed from subdirectory, the permissions on that directory need to be changed, and any other upstream directory. That's essentially the clarification I needed above and beyond the previous comments, thus I thought it helpful. I am new to this so I will try to be more clear in the future. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the screenshot that is in the link.